# How to tell when a degree sequence has a unique unlabelled graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

While solving the problem "Determine all graphs with exactly one pair of vertices equal degree (all other degrees are distinct)" for my intro to combinatorics class I was wondering if there is a way to tell when a degree sequence only has one unlabelled graph. I couldn't find any other threads related to this question about general (simple & undirected) graphs.

For the specific problem I was working on, I have the graphs on n vertices with degree sequences:
$(1,2,\dots,a,a,\dots,n-2,n-1)\text{ and }(0,1,2,\dots,b,b,\dots n-3,n-2)$ and this is how I determined the graphs that follow the degree sequence is unique.

Based on how you can construct a graph with degree sequence $$(1,2,\dots,a,a,\dots,n-2,n-1)$$ I feel like it should be obvious that it has a unique unlabelled graph as:

> 1.) Create edges from one vertex to all others (so you have all points of degree one and one of degree n-1)

> 2.) Then continue by choosing any other point of degree one and create edges to all other vertex of degree one until your chosen vertex has degree n-2 (this should leave one vertex of degree one)

> 3.) Then continue by choosing any other point of degree two and create edges to all other vertex of degree two until your chosen vertex has degree n-3 (this should leave one vertex of degree two)

> Continue this until you have exactly two vertices of the same degree

A similar algorithm works for creating a graph of degree sequence $(0,1,2,\dots,b,b,\dots n-3,n-2)$ and from there I found that $b=\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$ and that the graphs from these two degree sequences are complements of each other so $a=(n-1)-\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\rfloor$.

Assuming this is correct, I was wondering when in general does a degree sequence have a unique unlabelled graph associated with it? I know typically this is not true. Is the case where this is only one pair of of vertices of equal degree the only time this is true (other than trivial sequences such as $(0,0,\dots,0)$ and $(1,1\dots,1)$)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A large class of graphs that do this are the [**threshold graphs**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threshold_graph). One way to define these is to say that we start with a $1$-vertex graph and repeatedly make it bigger with one of two operations:

- Add a vertex adjacent to all existing vertices, or
- Add an isolated vertex.

The graphs in the question are threshold graphs: they are obtained when we alternate the two operations.

The degree sequence of a threshold graph uniquely determines it - the idea is that the last vertex we added has unambiguous connections to the rest of the graph, and is identifiable from its degree. (Either it is adjacent to all other vertices, or to none of them.) If you remove it, you get the threshold graph at the previous stage, and then you can repeat until you're back at the $1$-vertex graph.

There are other examples. For example, the degree sequence $(2,2,2,2,2)$ uniquely determines the $5$-cycle $C_5$. However, threshold graphs have a stronger property: their degree sequence uniquely determines the *labeled* graph. That is, if I give you vertices $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_n$ and their desired degrees $d_1, d_2, \dots, d_n$, and ask you which edges $v_i v_j$ exist, there is a unique answer for threshold graphs. (By contrast, there are many $5$-cycles on these $5$ vertices, all of which have degree sequence $(2,2,2,2,2)$.) Actually, we can prove:

**Theorem.** Threshold graphs are the only graphs strongly determined by their degree sequence, in the sense described in the previous paragraph.

**Proof.** As before, we can use the recursive definition of a threshold graph to induct. To do this, all we have to prove is that if a graph is strongly determined by its degree sequence, then it must have a vertex adjacent to either all other vertices, or to none of them. Then we can delete that vertex, adjust the degrees of everything else appropriately, and repeat on what's left.

To prove this, let $x$ be any highest-degree vertex. First, I claim that no neighbors of $x$ can be adjacent to non-neighbors of $x$. Suppose not: suppose that some vertex $x'$ adjacent to $x$ has a neighbor $y$ which is *not* adjacent to $x$. We cannot have $x'$ be adjacent to $x$, all neighbors of $x$, and also $y$. So there is some vertex $y'$ which is adjacent to $x$, but not $x'$. We get a new graph with the same degree sequence by deleting edges $xy', x'y$ and adding edges $xy, x'y'$ instead. That can't happen.

So if we look at $x$ and its neighbors, they form a connected component. In fact, that component must be the only nontrivial component of the graph. Suppose that there is an edge $xx'$ and also an edge $zz'$ in a different connected component. Then, once again, we get a new graph with the same degree sequence by deleting edges $xx'$, $zz'$ and adding edges $xz$, $x'z'$ instead. That can't happen.

As a result, either $x$ is adjacent to every other vertex, or - if there is some vertex $z$ it's not adjacent to - $z$ is an isolated vertex. This is exactly what we wanted to finish the proof by induction.

Comment: This was very very insightful. Glad there was such a nice answer to this. Thank you!